# Como coletar informações de uso da internet para iPhone com Xamarin / monotouch

Tags: xamarin, iphone, xamarin.ios, mono

Estou precisando coletar informações de uso da internet no iphone , o código em c# abaixo que estou utilizando só me retorna valores zerados.

estou utilizando a classe certa ?

tem alguma referência que preciso adicionar no xamarin ?

no mono me aparece 3 tipos de classes , concidentemente a interface "MacOsIPv4InterfaceStatistics" retorna fixo sempre o valor 0.

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.NetworkInformation/IPv4InterfaceStatistics.cs

1. Win32IPv4InterfaceStatistics
2. LinuxIPv4InterfaceStatistics
3. MacOsIPv4InterfaceStatistics

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Net;
   using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   using System.Threading;
   using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
   ```

   namespace Taximetro
   {
       public delegate void Update();

   ```
   public static class ControleUso
   {
       public static long controller;

       public static long BytesReceivedWiFi;
       public static long BytesSentWiFi;

       public static long BytesReceived3G;
       public static long BytesSent3G;

       public static Update UpdateMethod;

       public static void DoWork()
       {    
           foreach (var netint in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) {
               var stats = netint.GetIPv4Statistics ();

               //WiFi
               //if (netint.Name.StartsWith ("en")) {
                   BytesReceivedWiFi += stats.BytesReceived;
                   BytesSentWiFi += stats.BytesSent;
               //}

               //3G
               if (netint.Name.StartsWith ("pdp_ip")) {
                   BytesReceived3G += stats.BytesReceived;
                   BytesSent3G += stats.BytesSent;
               }
           }
           controller++;
           if (UpdateMethod != null) {
               UpdateMethod ();
           }
           Thread.Sleep (1000);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Respondida através do link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256093/how-to-collect-data-usage-information-from-the-internet-to-iphone-with-xamarin

Comment: Traga a resposta pra cá. Poste como resposta e aceite ela.